# change view controller from didSelectItemAt custom CollectionViewCell inside a custom TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view inside tableview cell, so I want to select the collection view cell and it goes to another view controller. So how do i do that?

I have tried myself, it's either does nothing, "Application tried to present modally an active controller", or "Attempt to present .. on .. whose view is not in the window hierarchy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `delegate` in **cell class** (Outside of cell class) and declare variable inside the class :

```
protocol CellSelectedDelegate { //Name them as you want
    func cellSelected()
}
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: CellSelectedDelegate?
}
```

Then in cell's `didSelectItem` :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   delegate?.cellSelected()
}
```

Now go to **controller** class where you have `tableView datasource` and `delegate` methods (assuming they are in controller class and not in another view) and add this in **cellForItem** method :

```
cell.delegate = self
```

And last part, implement `custom delegate` method in controller class :

```
extension YourController: CellSelectedDelegate {
    func cellSelected() {
       //Present next controller here
    }
}
```

Comment: got error for `cell.delegate = self `. Cannot assign value of type TableViewCell to type CellSelectedDelegate

Comment: did you implement the last step too ?

Comment: yes, i did. the collection view is inside custom tableview cell, does it matter?

Comment: i figured it out, the `delegate` variable should be put inside the **TableViewCell** class. Thanks!